# How to count frequency of a element in numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, counter, counting, numpy-ndarray

I have a 3 D numpy array which contains elements with repetition. 
    
        `counterTraj.shape
        (13530, 1, 1`

For example counterTraj contains such elements: I have shown few elements only:

````
         array([[[136.]],

       [[129.]],

       [[130.]],

       ...,

       [[103.]],

       [[102.]],

       [[101.]]])
```
````

I need to find frequency of different element: Example: 136 count 5 (say), 101 count 12 (say). The array elements are not fixed and changes with input data. I try following:
    
        `from collections import Counter
        Counter(counterTraj)`

    Following error generates:

```
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent 
    call last)
    <ipython-input-408-e3584b29b0bd> in <module>()
         11 counterTraj=np.vstack(counterTraj)
        12 counterTraj=counterTraj.reshape(len(counterTraj),1,1)
    ---> 13 Counter(counterTraj)
```

> ```
>     /usr/lib/python3.6/collections/__init__.py in __init__(*args, 
>    **kwds)
>          533             raise TypeError('expected at most 1 arguments, 
>       got %d' % len(args))
>           534         super(Counter, self).__init__()
>       --> 535         self.update(*args, **kwds)
>          536 
>        537     def __missing__(self, key):
>
>      /usr/lib/python3.6/collections/__init__.py in update(*args, 
>     **kwds)
>          620                     super(Counter, self).update(iterable) # 
>      fast path when counter is empty
>          621             else:
>       --> 622                 _count_elements(self, iterable)
>        623         if kwds:
>        624             self.update(kwds)
>
>      TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
> ```

How to find occurence of element with frequency and find highest frequency element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`numpy.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) with `return_counts=True` parameter, which will return the count of each of the elements in the array.

```
# sample array
In [89]: np.random.seed(23)
In [90]: arr = np.random.randint(0, 10, 20)

In [92]: a, cnts = np.unique(arr, return_counts=True)
In [94]: high_freq, high_freq_element = cnts.max(), a[cnts.argmax()]

In [95]: high_freq, high_freq_element
Out[95]: (4, 9)
```

---

For selecting only the elements which appear above a certain frequency threshold, you can use:

```
In [96]: threshold = 2

# select elements which occur only more than 2 times
In [97]: a[cnts > threshold]
Out[97]: array([3, 5, 6, 9])
```

Comment: It worked . I need to take elements only with count greater than 5 (say). How to do  this after your result?