# How to remove row of elements with condition in 3 D numpy array?

Tags: arrays, numpy

I have a 3 D numpy array with 5 data which is of following shape (5,1,1)

```
a=
arrray([[[0,2,4]],
[[2,6,3]],
[[1,6,9]],
[[4,3,10]]
[[3,3,8]]])
```

Based on second element of array, the array is to be adjusted. [How to count frequency of a element in numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55812146/6189499) With this the occurence of second element is calculated. 2 comes single.6 and 3 is repeated twice. Here I want to remove array element whose occurrence is less than 2.
In case the first row [0,2,4] is needed to be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using [`bincount`](https://het.as.utexas.edu/HET/Software/Numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html):

```
In [11]: bins = np.bincount(a[:, 0, 1])

In [22]: a[bins[a[:, 0, 1]] > 1]
Out[22]:
array([[[ 2,  6,  3]],

       [[ 1,  6,  9]],

       [[ 4,  3, 10]],

       [[ 3,  3,  8]]])
```

One could also use pandas to do this:

```
In [21]: pd.DataFrame(a[:, 0, :]).groupby(1)[0].transform('size')
Out[11]:
0    1
1    2
2    2
3    2
4    2
Name: 0, dtype: int64

In [22]: pd.DataFrame(a[:, 0, :]).groupby(1)[0].transform('size') > 1
Out[22]:
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
Name: 0, dtype: bool

In [23]: a[pd.DataFrame(a[:, 0, :]).groupby(1)[0].transform('size') > 1]
Out[23]:
array([[[ 2,  6,  3]],

       [[ 1,  6,  9]],

       [[ 4,  3, 10]],

       [[ 3,  3,  8]]])
```

---

Note if the max size of the ints is very large np.bincount will be inefficient. There may also be a way to use np.unique with return_counts to do this:

```
In [31]: nums, counts = np.unique(a[:, 0, 1], return_counts=True)

In [32]: a[counts[np.searchsorted(nums, a[:, 0, 1])] > 1]
Out[32]:
array([[[ 2,  6,  3]],

       [[ 1,  6,  9]],

       [[ 4,  3, 10]],

       [[ 3,  3,  8]]])
```